# Content 100% height between header and footer

Tags: html, css

I've been seeing a lot of questions about this, but none of them got me a nice solution to this problem. It's the typical no scroll intro page. The header can have x pixels but the footer is gonna be responsive (will be taller in tablets and mobiles). I can't really get my wrapper to be 100% height of the space between header and footer without pulling my footer outside and then centering vertically the content in the wrapper.

Any solution?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flex boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). `flex: 1` container will take as much space as it can.

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper .content {
  flex: 1;
}

.wrapper .header {
  height: 100px;
}
```